# Ruby PHP MD5 Incompatible - How is this possible?

Tags: php, ruby, md5

How is this possible? I can't get Ruby to give me the same MD5 as PHP does and can't figure this out... I thought encoding, but it seems I've managed to keep every file in the same format.

**PHP Code:** (result: bfa7df865d9f4aff62c4643d0e1cb33b)

```
echo md5("9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@#@akskd9");
```

**Ruby Code with Digest-MD5:** (result: bd53907a1b47e9a381ee663ec75b59f4)

```
require 'digest/md5'
puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest("9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@#@akskd9")
```

**Ruby Code with HMAC-MD5:** (result: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e)

```
require 'hmac-md5'
puts HMAC::MD5.new("9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@#@akskd9").hexdigest
```

Comment: A newline character after the ! might have something to do with it

Comment: Mark, is that a control sequence I'm not aware of? Because I don't have a newline character in there at all ... unless it's through a control sequence like \n or something, which I don't have ...

Comment: It looks like there's a newline in the code display in your post

Comment: Nah, it was fixed using single quotes, see below. It's strange ruby quirk it seems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest('9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@#@akskd9')
```

Comment: @RomanMittermayr Then there must be a slight difference between the PHP and Ruby input in your code. I just ran this on my computer and got `bfa7df865d9f4aff62c4643d0e1cb33b`

Comment: Yes, but I realized I was using single quotes and it makes a difference. Check my answer now.

Comment: Yes single quotes it is!!! Why is that?? (I'll accept this in a minute or two when it let's me, but this fixes it).

Comment: Because the string is evaluated differently inside of double quotes and the hash `#` character is throwing it off. To be honest, I'm not entirely sure why (since I believe ruby control sequence for including variables in strings is `#{...}` (notice the curly braces).

Comment: `#@akskd9` will try and include the instance variable named `akskd9`. The critical part is the `#@` together, not just the `#`.

Comment: @Tomdarkness Gah! Forgot about the `@` sign. Thanks for commenting on this one - personally not a ruby guy.

Comment: A bit more elaboration on the #@ and @## feature here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091156/why-does-this-string-interpolation-work-in-ruby

Comment: Pro tip: don't use double quotes for strings unless you are interpolating or need the special escapes, default to single quotes so that double quotes will give you a heads up to check the string for interpolation.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah, I use that philosophy in PHP as well. Actually, even when I could use double quotes, I use single and concat. Then it's VERY explicit about what I want.

Answer (score 2):

It is the combination of "#@" that makes it want to treat "@akskd9" at the end of the string as a variable.

For example:

```
@akskd9 = "foobar"
puts "9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@#@akskd9"

=> 9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@foobar
```

..without the # in there, then it ignores the @ symbol:

```
@akskd9 = "foobar"
puts "9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@@akskd9"

=> 9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@@akskd9
```

...interesting though, without the {...} after the #, it treats the rest of the string as a variable.

```
@ak = "foobar"
puts "9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@#@akskd9"

=> 9jdaksjdfosdjsljz91m1wms0zkzd0k0askd1m2l3!@3@
```