# How does string interpolation work without #{..} syntax?

Tags: ruby, string, string-interpolation

The code below is taken from page 118 of the Pickaxe book. Can someone explain to me why we do not need to do `#{@name}` to do interpolation?

```
class TaxCalculator
  def get_tax(amount)
    "#@name on #{amount} = #{@block.call(amount)}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the expression to be interpolated is just a reference to a global, instance or class variable, then the braces can be omitted. The braces are only required for more complex expressions.

However, there is a debate about whether omitting the braces is a good idea from a style and readability perspective.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a good answer to this question here:

[Why does string interpolation work in Ruby when there are no curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091156/why-does-this-string-interpolation-work-in-ruby)

In short: It's possible to spare the {} when you use a global, a class or an instance variable.

Comment: No need to duplicate an answer when there is already a sufficient answer both on this question and on the duplicate question.

Comment: This answer was written 4 minutes after Vidya's, which makes me think that it was written before Vidya's was posted - and misterbeaker simply missed that it had been posted in the meantime.