# Strange // syntax in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

At http://janlelis.github.io/ruby-bad-parts/#19 I can notice some strange example of Ruby syntax.

```
>> a = "Eurucamp #\n"
>> a.gsub /#$//, ''
# => "Eurucamp #"
```

I'm not Ruby programmer, but I'm wondering why it works, and what it does?

Comment: That looks like a regex literal

Comment: In addition to the answers below, I'd also note that gsub does not require you to pass a regular expression to it, a string works just fine. Therefore, `a.gsub $/, ''` would work just as well in this case and be more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [`$/`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+variables) global variable means `\n` in Ruby.

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > a = "Eurucamp #\n"
 => "Eurucamp #\n" 
2.0.0-p0 :002 > a.gsub /#$//, ''
 => "Eurucamp #" 
2.0.0-p0 :003 > $/
 => "\n" 
2.0.0-p0 :004 > /#$//.source
 => "\n" 
2.0.0-p0 :005 > a.gsub /##$//, ''
 => "Eurucamp " 
2.0.0-p0 :006 > /##$//.source
 => "#\n"
```

In your Regexp patteren you are telling [`Stirng#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) method, that in the source string if you find `"\n"`, replace it with a empty string(`''`). Using [`Regexp#source`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-source) you will always get back the *original string of the pattern*, so I did use `/#$//.source`, and found that it is `'\n'`.

```
/#$//
 ^^^ <~~~ string interpolation happened, which is a shortcut of #{$\}
```

See this post [Why does this string interpolation work in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091156/why-does-this-string-interpolation-work-in-ruby/10091782#10091782) as commented by **@rampion**.

Comment: Just wondering, do you know why regex doesn't match `#` in this case then?

Comment: Ruby string interpolation is normally `#{...}` except `#@ivar` is shorthand for `#{@ivar}` and `#$gvar` is shorthand for `#{$gvar}`

Comment: @xfix: Only global and instances variables in double quoted string contexts, `#{...}` is required for non-global and non-instance variable expressions. This is one of the dumb misfeatures in Ruby that seemed like a good idea at the time but turned out to be not so good.

Comment: @rampion Doing inspections I got to know why that result.. But did not know what you and *muistoshort* mentioned.. Thanks both of you.. Any source where you found this information..

Comment: @muistooshort You are right - *Only global and instances variables in double quoted string contexts*. But the same is also true in the context of regular expression.

Comment: A regex *is* a *double quoted string context* in that it allows string interpolation, just like `"..."`, `%Q{...}`, `%W[...]`, and heredocs.