# < > inside a Ruby String

Tags: ruby

I was reading something else posted by a user on here explaining how yield statements work in Ruby. Part of the code he was using was :

```
print_list( [1,2,3], 23 ) { |n| "<#{n}>"}
```

what do the < > mean inside the string? It's such a simple question but I haven't been able to find out the answer to it.

Comment: they have no meaning. They're just characters in the string.

Comment: It cannot be told out of context.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple misunderstanding (false assumption) and is highly unlikely to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: You are referring to http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/51c72e759c4e9d410501df42, right? It's about *formatting* the output, in this case: enclosing the numbers in angle brackets / chevrons.

Answer (score 5):

In a [string literal](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals) neither `<` nor `>` have any implied meaning - although such might have meaning in the output or use of the resulting string.

Only [escape sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Backslash_Notation) and `#` (in interpolated literals) have intrinsic meaning.

Comment: One more point in case of *interpolation*, `@`,`@@` and `$` are also have intrinsic meanings..

Comment: @ArupRakshit It's definitely good to keep in mind, although I think that simply means [that the braces can be omitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091156/why-does-string-interpolation-work-in-ruby-when-there-are-no-curly-braces) - i.e. in conjunction with `#` only.

Comment: Yes... right! That I thought I should mention in my previous comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

These characters are just a part of [string.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html)

And any character which lies inside #{ } will be evaluated, which is also referred to Interpolation