# unterminated string meets end of file

Tags: ruby

Following is my code:

```
md5 = Digest::MD5.new
md5 << "!@#$"
```

Then comes the error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):46: unterminated string meets end of file
```

What is wrong? And how can I calculate the md5 hash of the string `"!@#$"`?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what is going on but a workaround would be to either escape the pound character: `"!@\#$"` or use single-quotes: `'!@#$'`. The problem may arise from the fact that `$` is the prefix for global variables in Ruby and you can use interpolation without curly braces on them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091156/why-does-string-interpolation-work-in-ruby-when-there-are-no-curly-braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to quote `#`:

```
> puts "!@\#$"
!@#$
```

Answer (score 3):

The hash `#` sign in double quoted strings is used for variable and expression substitution. In this case, you are substituting the value of the global variable `$"` into the string, but you are not closing the string. The syntactically correct way of expressing that would be

```
"!@#$"" # Note the extra closing quotes
```

However, it seems that you actually don't want to do variable substitution anyway, in which case you should always use single quoted strings:

```
'!@#$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the string you got is in a double apostrophe (") - so it is interpreted. And you have a hash (#) inside, so it is trying to do expression substitution. Put the string in a single apostrophe:

```
md5 << '!@#$'
```