# Hide part of email domain

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

I'm trying to hide domain part of emails in my views when a user tries to reset the password, I'm using gsub but I'm having a problem with the union of 2 characters.

example:

```
"myemail@example.com".gsub(/.{0,4}@/,'####@')
```

I got this result:

```
"my###\#@example.com"
```

I don't wanna that \ in the middle of the ##, I entered the console and if I just write `'#@'` 
I got `"\#@"` ,  I don't know how to escape these characters.

with this method i also have a problem, if the domain is less then 4 letters i still put 4 '#'s in the domain. But my primary concern is about the junction of '#@'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine; the # is being escaped for you by irb or pry to disambiguate in its pretty print, since #@ can refer to interpolation of a global variable (see [Why does string interpolation work in Ruby when there are no curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091156/why-does-string-interpolation-work-in-ruby-when-there-are-no-curly-braces)).  The backslash is not actually in the string, which you can verify by printing it explicitly:

```
print("myemail@example.com".gsub(/.{0,4}@/,'####@'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `@`, as part of `@example`, is not escaped and is preceded by `'#'`, Ruby inserts the value of the instance variable `@example`.

Suppose:

```
@example = 'hi'
"my####@example.com" #=> "my###.com"
```

If there is no instance variable `@example`, referencing it returns `nil`, which is converted to an empty string.

```
"my####@example.com" #=> "my###.com"
```

This can also be done with global variables:

```
$example = 'ho'
"my####$example.com" #=> "my###ho.com"
```

and with class variables:

```
@@example = 'hum'
"my####@@example.com" #=> "my###hum.com"
```